# Why is exposing my queen for capture better in this position (According to computer analysis)?

Tags: analysis, tactics, knights, queens, pins

In one my of my game, the following position appeared (me white):[image]

Computer analysis says that I should have played `Nf3` (exposing my queen being captured by the bishop). In the proposed scenario by the computer, the opponent will play `h3` (capturing my knight) and so I can capture his bishop with my queen.

But another scenario could occur, the opponent will capture my queen with the bishop and I can then play `Nf7` (something like the fried liver) and the opponent moves his queen and I can capture the rook (Or he can capture my queen and I capture the bishop with the rook but in this case he can then move his queen to prevent the somewhat-similar-to fried liver attack). But In such case, I think the opponent is in a better situation: He got my queen and I got a pawn and a rook (or a pawn and a bishop), He can no more castle but he has much more material so he can do well.

So why does the computer says that this is a better move? I tried `h3` to attach the opponent bishops but computer says this is not a good move!

An explanation for why such an analysis is valid is highly appreciated

Comment: Is this the right diagram?

Comment: You can't play Nf3 in the diagram position, because your knight is already on f3.

Comment: don't forget to mark my answer as accepted, if it answered your question.

Comment: I think you mean Nxe5 from f3.

Answer (score 15):

Your description of the computer's suggestions doesn't quite match the position, but if you mean the computer suggests Nxe5, that is correct, as Bxd1 leads to a variation of [Legal's Mate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9gal_Trap).

1. Nxe5  Bxd1
2. Bxf7+ Ke7
3. Nd5#

If, instead,

1. Nxe5 dxe5
2. Qxg4

and white has won a pawn, and has a big lead in development.

Comment: Could you please expand after Nxe5 dxe5?

Comment: @PabloS.Ocal done.

Comment: Note that after 1.Nxe5 dxe5 2.Qxg4 Nxc2 3.Rb1 soon followed by f2-f4, White doesn't actually wins a pawn, but he enjoys a great lead in development and initiative on the light squares.

Comment: Down voter care to add a comment?

Comment: There are cowardly stalkers who go around downvoting good answers.

Comment: @cyriacantony on my screen there is a bN on d4.

Comment: But I should add that the aggressive 1.Ne5 de5 2.Qg4 Nc2 3.f4!? (instead of 3.Rb1 in my comment 3 years ago) 3...Na1 4.fe5, while unnecessary, is probably winning as well.